# Wine user32 message dispatch

Tags: c++, wine

From my understanding a program.exe  , use the SendMessage() located in user32.dll.so .

But also my program.exe must receive some messages ,for example when user click minimize or close buttons .
How these messages are sent to program.exe?
From where they came?What dll?
For example if winecfg have "Allow window manager to control the window" ,how my program.exe will be closed if user click on close button (X on top bar) ,what message my program will receive?

Sorry if this seams stupid questions ,but I try to figure out what wine component send to my app the close message for example

Comment: Its all wine magic of course :P

Comment: I have a program who is trying to send messages when his hwnd was already distroyed and the result is a crash.I try to make some test to see what happens if close message is not received in my app,and some more tests

Comment: Does it work properly on a regular windows system?

Comment: Yes it does , is visual studio c++ 6 ,crash if a menu is oppened but user click X on top bar .If "Allow window manager to control the window" is off problem gone

Comment: MSDEV.EXE loads DEVSHL.DLL .After user click X to close the app DEVSHL.DLL ,want to send some messages using SendMessage() .Any ideea how to prevent DEVSHL.DLL to receive the close event ?

Comment: don't expect wine to behave as windows. It makes a lot of effort to mimic windows, but it is still far from perfection

Comment: I just looking for ideeas , not for code .I need to implement my own code case wine source tree dnt get all ugly patches ,but for myself if they just works is fine.I dnt need my code to look perfect ,I jut need the apps to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window manager sends ClientMessage with type WM_PROTOCOLS and the protocol value WM_DELETE_WINDOW.

This is handled in dlls/winex11.drv/event.c: X11DRV_ClientMessage() -> handle_wm_protocols().